# Laravel admin crud project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, crud

I'm using **laravel** and I need solution about admin side. I dont want to **reinvent a wheel** and i think good Admin panel (crud, cms) is available on laravel.

```
any suggestion ?
```

Comment: I have used https://github.com/zofe/rapyd-laravel . Easy ,fast and good for CRUD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't used it myself, but this seems to be popular: https://packagist.org/packages/frozennode/administrator

Others I found:
https://packagist.org/packages/shin1x1/laravel-table-admin
https://packagist.org/packages/pingpong/admin

The last 2 seem very new so I suggest checking out the top 1 first.

Comment: I'm searching some strong cms or crud admin like joomla and drupal but builder on laravel ...

Comment: Maybe checkout http://octobercms.com/ then. :)

Comment: Maybe orchestra platform

Answer (score 4):

Not popular as others,  but  give it a try to rapyd-laravel
It's a CRUD package for Laravel 4/5   widgets based (forms, grids, etcetera)
it's a really fast way to implement an crud administration interface in few lines of code:

https://github.com/zofe/rapyd-laravel

http://www.rapyd.com

Answer (score 2):

you can also check out this package 
https://github.com/serverfireteam/panel

easy to use and also has a nice design,
this package benefits from 
https://github.com/zofe/rapyd-laravel

Answer (score 1):

A new version of PongoCMS is in the making as well: http://pongocms.com/. The current version works on Laravel 3, but PongoCMS v2 is based on Laravel 4.